# With Rails 3, What's the easiest way to protect an entire site from un-authenticated users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, routes

I'm using Devise for authentication for my site.  An unauthenticated visitor should be able to only see: the welcome page, the sign-up page, and the login page.  To unauthenticated visitors, all other pages/routes would be wholly inaccessible.

I looked at Cancan, but that seems like much, much more than I need.

I saw something else that suggested doing it at the Apache level, but life is way to short to be mucking around with web server settings.

I saw an article or two on using a session or user based before_filter, but it looks like I would have to modify each method in each controller.

Is there some other approach?  It would be great if I could identify my routes as those publicly accessible and those requiring authentication.  Is that possible?  Or can I easily disable a complete controller based on current_user?

Just looking for something that is very simple and straightforward.  Extra credit for something that errors-out gracefully.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a method to Application Controller that forbids access to nonauthenticated users (using `before_filter`) and overwrite this method for controllers where you want to give them access.

So in application controller:

```
before_filter :only_authenticated_users_are_welcome

def only_authenticated_users_are_welcome
  !user.blank?
end
```

And to grant access to some pages and in their controller:

```
def only_authenticated_users_are_welcome
  true
end
```

Or add some more logic to grant access only to some actions within the controller.

Comment: Thanks!  Works well.  Instead of "!user.blank?" I used Devise's "!user_signed_in?" method.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with klew's answer, but instead of overriding the definition of only_authenticated_users_are_welcome, you can:

```
skip_before_filter :only_authenticated_users_are_welcome, :except => [:foo, :bar]
```

in controllers which should *not* be protected, and note the use of :except to indicate methods for which the before_filter should *not* be skipped. You can also use :only => [:foo, :bar] to indicate the skip should *only* be for the selected methods.